# How do you sort the items in a custom taxonomy meta box?

Tags: post-meta

I used the following code to reorder the custom taxonomy (and other) meta boxes on the right side of my custom post type's edit page:

```
// Change order of taxonomy meta boxes on artist edit screen
add_filter( 'get_user_option_meta-box-order_artist', 'artist_metabox_order' );
function artist_metabox_order( $order ) {
    return array(
        'side' => join( 
            ",", 
            array(       // vvv  Arrange here as you desire
                'submitdiv',
                'event_typediv',
                'artist_typediv',
                'genrediv',
                'subscription_leveldiv',
                'salespersondiv',
                'postimagediv',
            )
        ),
    );
}
```

The problem is, the sort order of the data inside the meta boxes is now screwed. It had been in alphabetical order within hierarchy, but now there seems to be no order at all. Did this filter somehow erase the order that had been there before?

Comment: This code alone will not affect the order of the term checklists. You could try switching to a bundled theme and disabling all plugins, then re-enabling plugins one by one to narrow down the culprit.

Comment: But this code DID change the order in the meta boxes. How do I get the data re-sorted?

Comment: Does it go back to normal when you remove this code? Did you try my suggestion? When I tested it, the order of the terms in the meta boxes were not affected by this code, which makes sense considering there is nothing in this code that would affect the term order. The order of the meta boxes themselves were affected of course, but that's expected. Perhaps there's some code using `pre_get_terms` or `parse_term_query` or another filter in `WP_Term_Query()` affecting the term list.

Comment: The effect persisted when I changed to a standard WP theme. When I removed the ordering filters from my custom post types, the sorting stayed the same, too. So you are right, the code is not the problem. So, how do I sort the items in the meta boxes? I don't see any code affecting the functions you mentioned.

Comment: By default, the terms should be sorted alphabetically, with checked terms being floated to the top, so something is apparently affecting that. It would really be best to find the source of the issue rather than piling code on top to try and fix it. The order can be changed using the `pre_get_terms`, `parse_term_query`, and `terms_clauses` filters. Perhaps others too. It might help prospective answerers if you could try and provide additional details such as how the terms are being ordered. Is it by term ID? Slug? Perhaps show a screenshot of what it looks like.